# In javaFX need object reference to node under mouse cursor

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

I need a reference to the object under the mouse cursor in a javaFX Pane (or ScrollPane)
The following code removes the node under the cursor from the Pane.

The node object is stored in an ArrayList and has a unique id. If I had a reference to the node object, it would be a simple matter to remove it from the list. I'd be happy just to be able to pull the id of the node object out of the target description supplied by the MouseEvent's description of the target, and use it to find my node in the list. Note: I am creating these nodes dynamically and they are nameless: myList.add(new TYPE()).

Here's the snippet that I'm using to remove the node in the Pane;

```
root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle (MouseEvent me) {
        // would like a line here that grabbed the reference to the target
        pane.getChildren().remove(me.getTarget());

    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't `me.getTarget()` the reference you want?

Comment: Yes! (After some testing)  Thanks James_D (we meet again). Who would have guessed!? I should stop reading the docs. me.getTarget() returns an EventTarget, which "specifies the path through which the event will travel when posted."  The reason I didn't think it was the reference is because its use in expressions like me.getTarget().getText() were failing to get past the compiler

Comment: The objects in my ArrayList are currently Text objects. If I use the for each looping construct with tl as my Text element, the syntax me.getTarget().getText() causes the complaint. The code follows

Comment: see coding example below -

Comment: Note that this only works because `Text` nodes are leaf nodes. If you were removing nodes that contain other nested nodes, then if you clicked on the nested node, `me.getTarget()` would return that nested node. You would have to write some extra code to determine the appropriate parent of `me.getTarget()` to remove. /cc @James_D

Answer (score 1):

It would be better for you to put the setOnMouseClicked listener to the node on which you want to remove from the list.

```
List<Node> listOfNodes = new ArrayList();
Node node = new Node();
listOfNodes.add(node);
node.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
    listOfNodes.remove(node);
});
```

Note: Better use ObservableList than the ordinary ArrayList especially if you want that node to be removed also out from the root pane.

Comment: You can automatically manage adding the listener to the node, and removing the listener from the node, with a list change listener on `root.getChildren()`

Comment: Warren: Lambda expressions notwithstanding, I don't have the luxury of naming the nodes as they are created on the fly, otherwise I could use the dot notation syntax to grab them. I simply want the reference to the node under the mouse cursor. No big deal, but I can't figure out how to get it from any of the docs I've been reading and the API docs are simply teasing me at this point. Obviously the JVM can find the node I'm looking for if it can interpret "me.getTarget()"

Comment: Jame_D: How will that help me find my node on my array list?

Answer (score 0):

To James_D: Reason for disbelief: the syntax that fails to get past the compiler is the statement containing the expression  me.getTarget().getText()  which is commented out. It seemed to me that that ought to have worked.

```
for (Text tl : textList)
   if ( (me.getTarget()) == (tl) )
       {
          System.out.println("HuRah!");
          System.out.println("text is " + tl.getText());
          //System.out.println("text is " + me.getTarget().getText());
          textList.remove(me.getTarget());                   
        }
```

Comment: `me.getTarget()` returns `EventTarget`. You need to cast it to `Text`: `((Text) me.getTarget()).getText()`.

Comment: Thanks Tomas - I knew about it returning Event target - whatever the &^%$ that is (see my comment above), but the last statement works fine without the cast. So I got fooled into thinking otherwise and it still won't make it past the compiler with the cast!

Comment: `textList.remove(me.getTarget())` works because `remove` works for any `Object`. What is the compiler error message for `System.out.println("text is " + ((Text) me.getTarget()).getText())`?

Comment: Hey Tomas: I neglected to parenthesize the entire first part of the expression as you indicated. Now it compiles when I write ( (Text) me.getTarget()).getText()   Thanks again. The universe is once again in alignment.

Comment: Love this site and the expertise it freely shares. Keep up the good work guys.